# window.open() popup doesn't show anything

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, bootstrap-4

I have a Django website [with this url](https://hamta.app/) that has this code in its template footer:

```html
<img referrerpolicy='origin' id = 'rgvjjxlzwlaoesgtfukzjxlz' style = 'cursor:pointer' onclick = 'window.open("https://logo.samandehi.ir/Verify.aspx?id=314061&p=xlaorfthaodsobpdgvkarfth", "Popup","toolbar=no, scrollbars=no, location=no, statusbar=no, menubar=no, resizable=0, width=450, height=630, top=30")' alt = 'logo-samandehi' src = 'https://logo.samandehi.ir/logo.aspx?id=314061&p=qftinbpdshwllymawlbqnbpd' />
```

which displays this image in the footer:

[image]

When it is clicked, it should display a popup page like this:

[image: this is in the footer of another website called "toplearn.com" which I just gave as an example, but it looks exactly like this page.]

(this is in the footer of another website called "toplearn.com" which I just gave as an example, but it looks exactly like this page.)

But it runs a blank page. Thank you for helping me find the problem

Comment: Because the link you provided doesn't show anything https://logo.samandehi.ir/Verify.aspx?id=314061&p=xlaorfthaodsobpdgvkarfth

Comment: @KonradLinkowski No, please check the address I mentioned as an example(toplearn.com). It has exactly the same code as mine, which doesn't open if you open it on a separate window, but it opens on the site itself by clicking on the image. Which is not the case with my site for reasons unknown to me.

Comment: The content of the popup is probably injected through parent

Comment: Something wrong with `samandehi.ir` itself. all other links are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<!-- onClick='openWindow()': run finction (openWindow) after user click on image --->
<img referrerpolicy='origin' id='rgvjjxlzwlaoesgtfukzjxlz' style='cursor:pointer' onClick='openWindow()' alt='logo-samandehi' src='https://logo.samandehi.ir/logo.aspx?id=314061&p=qftinbpdshwllymawlbqnbpd' />

<script>
  // function openWindow
  function openWindow() {
    window.open("https://logo.samandehi.ir/Verify.aspx?id=314061&p=xlaorfthaodsobpdgvkarfth", "Popup", "toolbar=no, scrollbars=no, location=no, statusbar=no, menubar=no, resizable=0, width=450, height=630, top=30");
  }
</script>
```